# Django test parallel with 1 DB

Tags: django, django-testing

I am trying to run my tests in parallel using `manage.py test --parallel`. By default this will use [a different DB for each thread](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-parallel).

> Each process gets its own database

Is it possible to only use one? Also is it a bad practice and why?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible to do this without overwritting of Django TestRunner.

Separate database increase isolation of your tests. This help to prevent appearence of flucky tests.

Comment: PS. If you really need to do this - probably you should check `django.test.runner._init_worker`.